# Setting 2 alarms with one receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I need to trigger two alarms. The first one fires correctly if its just one alarm. If I include the code for the second one, the alarms overlap and the desired functionality is not achieved. My question is do I need two broadcast receivers or I can do it with one?
first alarm:

```
    public void triggerEnable(boolean enableData, int hourInDay, int minInDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //if (enableData) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minInDay);
 //     } else {
 //         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
//          calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minInDay);
//      }
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

}
```

broadcast receiver:

```
    @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(CONN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        boolean enableConn = intent.getBooleanExtra("FLAG_KEY", false);
           objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, enableConn); 
        //what do I do here to have different values for the second alarm?
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using single broadcastreceiver but using pending intents with different ids.
Right now what you are doing is sending multiple pending intents with same ID. Because of this they are overlapping. What you need to do is send another pending intent with a different ID.
**First intent**

```
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**Second intent**

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then with the help of alarmManager, fire these pending intents to be received by your broadcastreceiver. 
Hope it helps

Comment: And how exactly do I fire these pending intents?

Answer (score 0):

As Stated in android doc.

**If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.**

I believe you need to set the timing one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two pending Intents.

```
Intent alarm1 = new Intent("com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm1 , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent alaram2 = new Intent("com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alaram2 , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then you have to register two broadcast receivers.

```
private static BroadcastReceiver alarm1= null;
private static BroadcastReceiver alaram2= null;

 alarm1= new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        if(CONN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        boolean enableConn = intent.getBooleanExtra("FLAG_KEY", false);
        objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, enableConn); 

      }

}

alaram2=new BroadcastReceiver(){
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
//put your code for the second alarm here

}
```

Try this. I am sure this will work.

Comment: I dont know but this one has some serious syntax errors. It isnt working.